# Spring async controller method with DeferredResult and logback-access for full request/response logging

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, logging, httpresponse, logback

Spring async controller method with `DeferredResult` and logback-access for full request/response logging. The problem is that for synchronous methods for example that return simple `String` request body is written into the log file but for methods that return Asynchronously logback-access fails to print response body. BTW, in last case headers get printed.

Logback-access is installed on container(Tomcat 8) level.

Let me know if I can provide more details